# WebpackHTMLPlugin output built references with a prefix

Tags: html-webpack-plugin

I have a configuration option for my Express app that determines whether to pull static content (JS, CSS, etc.) from a separate URL (e.g. using webpack-dev-server) or serving it "inline" via `express.static()` in the Express app. So I need to output a different origin depending on that configuration:

```
<script src="{STATIC_CONTENT_PATH}/[resource reference]"></script>
```

where `{STATIC_CONTENT_PATH}` is the web server's origin if serving inline, or the content server's origin if running separately. So far, I've only been able to get it to output a path that is relative to the site root (`/publicPath/[resource reference]`). Is there an easy way to add a prefix to the path used in the tags that the plugin outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any existing option to do this, so I just used a `template`, which contains the following:

```
<%= _.map(htmlWebpackPlugin.files.js, (path) => `<script src="${htmlWebpackPlugin.options.staticContentURL}${path}"></script>` ).join("") %>
```

(I also passed through the URL as a config option to the plugin)